# mysql calculating a running total per specific dimensions

Tags: mysql

I have the following formula that creates the following output

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.precip AS 'daily precip',
SUM(t2.precip) AS 'cum. precip'
FROM rainfall AS t1 INNER JOIN rainfall AS t2
ON t1.date >= t2.date
GROUP BY t1.date;


  +------------+--------------+-------------+
  | date       | daily precip | cum. precip |
  +------------+--------------+-------------+
  | 2014-06-01 |         1.50 |        1.50 |
  | 2014-06-02 |         0.00 |        1.50 |
  | 2014-06-03 |         0.50 |        2.00 |
  | 2014-06-04 |         0.00 |        2.00 |
  | 2014-06-05 |         1.00 |        3.00 |
  +------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to calculate this said table but by state, the desired output is as follows;

```
------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
    State.  | date       | daily precip | cum. precip |
------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
 NJ         | 2014-06-01 |         1.50 |        1.50 |
 NJ         | 2014-06-02 |         0.00 |        1.50 |
 NJ         | 2014-06-03 |         0.50 |        2.00 |
 NJ         | 2014-06-04 |         0.00 |        2.00 |
 NJ         | 2014-06-05 |         1.00 |        3.00 |
 NY         | 2014-06-01 |         1.50 |        1.50 |
 NY         | 2014-06-02 |         0.00 |        1.50 |
 NY         | 2014-06-03 |         0.50 |        2.00 |
 NY         | 2014-06-04 |         0.00 |        2.00 |
 NY         | 2014-06-05 |         1.00 |        3.00 |
 -----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What is the original data in the table? What is `precip`? Is it functionally dependent on `date`? if not, then selecting it is kind of meaningless. If yes, then your schema is not normalized.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+ then use window functions:

```
SELECT
    state,
    date,
    precip,
    SUM(precip) OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY date) AS `cum. precip`
FROM rainfall
ORDER BY
    state,
    date;
```

For earlier versions of MySQL, use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    state,
    date,
    precip,
    (SELECT SUM(r2.precip) FROM rainfall r2
     WHERE r2.state = r1.state AND r2.date <= r1.date) AS `cum. precip`
FROM rainfall r1
ORDER BY
    state,
    date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the `State` column into the `ON` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.State, t1.date, t1.precip AS 'daily precip',
SUM(t2.precip) AS 'cum. precip'
FROM rainfall AS t1 INNER JOIN rainfall AS t2
ON t1.State = t2.State AND t1.date >= t2.date
GROUP BY t1.State, t1.date, t1.precip;
```

Note: I also included `t1.precip` in the GROUP BY clause for the case if `(State, date)` is not defined as UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY.